# Attempted to call an undefined method named "newInstance" of class "Swift_Message"

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Since a few days I can't send email anymore using Symfony and Swiftmailer, though I'm using the code from the documentation

```
private function _sendResetPasswordEmail(UserInterface $user)
{   
    $subject = $this->get('translator')->trans('email-title-reset-password');
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom('contact@example.com')
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'reset-password-email.html.twig',
                ['user' => $user]
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

and it used to work

and now I can see in the logs

```
"Attempted to call an undefined method named "newInstance" of class "Swift_Message"
```

what could have changed ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually while posting the question and linking to the documentation, I was surprised to see it was updated

Now it is

```
 $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
```

instead of

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
       ->setSubject('Hello Email')
```

since the release of swiftmailer6 according to the changelog

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/CHANGES#L24

it's a pity there wasn't a "deprecated" period.

Answer (score 1):

@allan.simon answer is right, but it might be simpler.

You can, but there is no need to pass `$subject` into `__constructor`.

Before

```php
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
```

Now

```php
$message = (new \Swift_Message())
```