# Symfony and Swift Mailer

Tags: swiftmailer

https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html
Documents are lacking some information, like all symfony documents are but my problem at moment is that how to instantiate the new Swift_SmtpTransport()?

I cannot find namespace for it. If i do like the document says, i get this error -> Attempted to load class "Swift_SmtpTransport" from namespace App\Controller.

plus, documents don't say how to instantiate Swift_Message class either. 
Trying container hasn't worked for me, like so -> $this->container->get

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here if you want to send a message -> [Attempted to call an undefined method named "newInstance" of class "Swift_Message"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447972/attempted-to-call-an-undefined-method-named-newinstance-of-class-swift-messag) 
I quote :

Now it is:
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject('Hello Email')
instead of

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
   ->setSubject('Hello Email')
```